# How do I both censor a command away from .bash_history and also be able to return to it with up arrow?

Tags: bash, command-history

When one prepends a space character to the command, it disappears from history. But this also causes the command to no not easily editable and re-runnable.

How do I make weaker version of space-censored command that only disappears from permanent history, not from in-memory one?

```
                                  `command`   ` command`  I want
Saved to .bash_history:            Yes           No         No
Can uparrow, edit and re-execute:  Yes           No         Yes
```

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, there's no such feature in bash.

A possible workaround is to put the command in an alias or function and omit the alias/function definition from the command history. You can still use the alias/function, and its uses will be written in the history file, but the function definition itself will remain in memory only. For example, in the following session, the command `mysql -p$(mysql_password)` will be written to the history file, but the password itself won't be since the `alias mysql_password=…` command has a leading space.

```
$ HISTCONTROL=ignorespace
$  alias mysql_password=$(echo swordfish)
$ mysql -p$(mysql_password)
```

If you want to edit the function definition, you can print it out with `declare -f foo` (`alias foo` for an alias) and use the output to define a new one (an external editor may help, or the [`shell-expand-line` readline function](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#index-shell_002dexpand_002dline-_0028M_002dC_002de_0029) which is bound to `C-M-e`).

Alternatively, switch to zsh and set the [`HISTORY_IGNORE` variable](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Parameters.html#index-HISTORY_005fIGNORE). Commands matching this pattern are stored in the in-memory history but not written to the history file. You can't decide on a command by command basis, but you can include a marker like `#dontstore` in the command and set `HISTORY_IGNORE='\#dontstore'`.

Comment: Is it necessary to escape `#` in setting `HISTORY_IGNORE`?

Comment: @muru In this case, because it's at the beginning, no. But in general, yes, if `extended_glob` is set (and who doesn't set it?), then `#` needs to be quoted if there's something else before it, because `a#` means “zero or more repetitions of `a`”.